Free and open source software to automate deployment of Docker images and use config files?
I'm looking for a software that can be used to deploy and configure web services like running Docker containers, one for the web service and one for the PostgreSQL database.
This software must run on Debian 12 (bookworm), and be installed from an apt repository. So that it is installed on a remote server.
The perfect solution would be:

when code is merged on a branch on GitLab, GitLab CI can trigger the start of the deployment on the remote server
the software reads the compose.yaml or docker-compose.yml file in order to:

pull images from the GitLab registry
use volumes defined in the YAML file


config files (which are versioned in the project) allow further configuration:

configure the hostname(s) for 1 or more services, e.g. a subdomain of a wildcard domain (1)
run any command before or after the deployment, like log in to the GitLab registry and pull images



(1): it's not an issue if the initial configuration require some CLI steps, since the software has to be given a wildcard domain in order to be able to respond through ports 80 and 443, it may be impossible to automate
Similar question but the answer doesn't suit these needs: Auto deploy docker containers from registry?
Because:

they rely on a GUI for configuration (CapRover)
they need extra configuration for each new project (Dokku)
they require a lot of knowledge to be used (Rancher / Kubernetes)

Please let me know if in fact one of these tools would fit, maybe I misread their documentation.

I have been using CapRover for a few days and it requires to use the GUI but it's only necessary to install the platform and to create apps.
Then we can configure GitLab CI to inform CapRover to pull Docker images from the GitLab registry then run them, and it works perfectly. It can generate HTTPS certificates automatically with a few clicks, which is a nice addition.

Ansible is a powerful automation tool that perfectly fits your requirements. While it's not a dedicated platform for deploying Docker containers, it offers the flexibility and control you need.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So you suggest to run Ansible from GitLab CI in order to perform deployments? Do you have any example to share? It would duplicate Ansible configuration in every project, while we have a dedicated repository to version our Ansible configuration files.
